# How to execute a perl script from a PL/SQL script?

Tags: plsql

I have a requirement to execute a perl script from a PL/SQL script. The perl script executes various system commands, and this piece is already developed. The piece I am having trouble with is executing the perl script from the PL/SQL code. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Look at [Tom Kyte's suggestion](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1474804744643)

Comment: I used this link: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:952229840241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute it as DBMS_SCHEDULER job with job_type => 'EXECUTABLE'.

> This specifies that the job is a job external to the database. External jobs are anything that can be executed from the operating system's command line.

Details are described in [Oracle's documentation for DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_sched.htm#i1000363)